# How would I "wrap" this not-quite-"by lazy" result caching function call in idiomatic Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I can't use "by [lazy](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Lazy.kt)" because the callbacks require `suspendCoroutine`, which borks in android if it blocks the main thread, so I have to use the following "cache the result" pattern over and over.   Is there a way to wrap it in a `funButUseCachedResultsIfTheyAlreadyExist` pattern to encapsulate the xCached object?

```
private var cameraDeviceCached: CameraDevice? = null

private suspend fun cameraDevice(): CameraDevice {
    cameraDeviceCached?.also { return it }
    return suspendCoroutine { cont: Continuation<CameraDevice> ->
        ... deep callbacks with cont.resume(camera) ...
    }.also {
        cameraDeviceCached = it
    }
}
```

When what I'd really like to write is

```
private suspend fun cameraDevice(): CameraDevice = theMagicFunction { cont ->
    ... deep callbacks with cont.resume(camera) ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a generalized solution by wrapping an `async` call as follows:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.LAZY

class LazySuspendFun<out T>(
        scope: CoroutineScope,
        private val block: suspend () -> T
) {
    private val deferred = scope.async(Dispatchers.Unconfined, LAZY) { block() }

    suspend operator fun invoke() = deferred.await()
}

fun <T> CoroutineScope.lazySuspendFun(block: suspend () -> T) = 
        LazySuspendFun(this, block)
```

This is a simple example of how you can use it. Note that we are able to compose them so that we use a lazy-inited value as a dependency to getting another one:

```
val fetchToken = lazySuspendFun<String> {
    suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
        Thread {
            info { "Fetching token" }
            sleep(3000)
            info { "Got token" }
            continuation.resume("hodda_")
        }.start()
    }
}

val fetchPosts = lazySuspendFun<List<String>> {
    val token = fetchToken()
    suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
        Thread {
            info { "Fetching posts" }
            sleep(3000)
            info { "Got posts" }
            continuation.resume(listOf("${token}post1", "${token}post2"))
        }
    }
}
```

On the calling side you must be inside some coroutine context so you can call the suspending functions:

```
myScope.launch {
   val posts = fetchPosts()
   ...
}
```

This solution is robust enough that you can concurrently request the value several times and the initializer will run only once.

Comment: It starts a thread which resumes the continuation. It's just for the sake of self-contained mock code, not something you should emulate in real code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178164/discussion-between-benjamin-h-and-marko-topolnik).

Answer (score 0):

I'll write this as an answer, since it's not possible to post much code in comments.

What you're looking for is something like this:

```
private suspend fun cameraDevice() = theMagicFunction {
    CameraDevice()
}()

suspend fun theMagicFunction(block: ()->CameraDevice): () -> CameraDevice {
    var cameraDeviceCached: CameraDevice? = null

    return fun(): CameraDevice {
        cameraDeviceCached?.also { return it }
        return suspendCoroutine { cont: Continuation<CameraDevice> ->
            cont.resume(block())
        }.also {
            cameraDeviceCached = it
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this will not compile, since closures cannot be suspendable, and neither are local functions.

Best I can suggest, unless I miss a solution there, is to encapsulate this in a class, if this variable bothers you too much.

Comment: "is to encapsulate this in a class" - agreed, I think I have to do that.

Comment: `block: suspend () -> CameraDevice` would be a type of suspendable closure.